# Naming lists dynamically in Python

Tags: python, dynamic, naming

As the title says I'm trying to name lists dynamically in Python. The purpose of the code is to create lists around consecutive letters. Here is my code:

```
consecutive_duplicates=["a","a","a","a","b","c","c","a","a","d","e","e","e","e","X"]

count=0
name=0

for i in consecutive_duplicates:
    if consecutive_duplicates[count]==consecutive_duplicates[count+1] or
              consecutive_duplicates[count]==consecutive_duplicates[count-1]:
        consecutive_duplicates[name].append(i)
        count=count+1
    else:
        consecutive_duplicates[name+1].append(i)
        name=name+1
```

I'm at a loss of how to name the lists. Obviously this doesn't work as it is. What would make it work?

I'm also having trouble defining the dynamic lists. How should I do that?

Comment: What is you expected output?

Comment: My expected output is a series of lists that contain consecutive letters. I will then turn them into a single list.

Comment: Please limit your "questions" to only 1 question per post. Also - have you considered using dictionaries?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lis = ["a","a","a","a","b","c","c","a","a","d","e","e","e","e","X"]
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(lis)]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b'], ['c', 'c'], ['a', 'a'], ['d'], ['e', 'e', 'e', 'e'], ['X']]
```

And instead of creating dynamic variables it's better to use a dict:

```
>>> dic = { 'lis'+str(i): list(g) for  i,(k,g) in enumerate(groupby(lis), 1)}
>>> dic['lis1']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
>>> dic['lis2']
['b']
```